# R: How to save base plot to a grid object, except from grid.echo()

Tags: r, plot, grid

Background: I used a wrapped `plot` function from the package `MatchIt` (a package for propensity scoring matching), and find difficulties in putting the graphs together on one page.

My solution: To convert the plots to grid objects first (using `grid.echo` and `grid.grab` from `gridGraphics` package), and then use `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` package to arrange them.

The problem: when using `grid.echo`, an error occurs: "Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0".

I figured out that this comes from the fact that part of the graph has all `FALSE` values. Instead of trying to hack the `grid.echo` function or the `plot` function, I would like to ask if there is another way of saving the `base plot` as `grobs` objects?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
### Generate data and the model
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(y=sample(c(0,1),20,replace=TRUE),x1=rnorm(20),x2=1:20)
library(MatchIt)
m.out <- matchit(y~x1+x2,data=df,method='nearest',replace=TRUE,ratio=2,discard="treat") 
### This one is OK because "discard" is set, so that the plot has none empty values in all parts    
m.out_none <- matchit(y~x1+x2,data=df,method='nearest',replace=TRUE,ratio=2,discard="none") 
### This one is NOT OK because "discard" is not set, so part of the plot is empty.

### function to convert base plot to grid objects
library(gridGraphics)
grab_grob <- function(){
    grid.echo()
    grid.grab()
}

plot(m.out_none,interactive=FALSE,type='jitter')
p1 <- grab_grob() ### Error here
plot(m.out,interactive=FALSE,type='jitter')
p2 <- grab_grob() ### No errors
```

Comment: In case anyone else run into similar problems in `grid.echo`: the bug is kindly fixed by Paul Murrell in the github version of gridGraphics.

Answer (score 1):

The two charts can be combined into a single output file with the `par()` function without having to convert the graphics to other object types. In this scenario we'll use `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` to instruct base R graphics to write two plots in one row. Using the example code from the original post, we generate the graphs as follows.

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(y=sample(c(0,1),20,replace=TRUE),x1=rnorm(20),x2=1:20)
library(MatchIt)
m.out <- matchit(y~x1+x2,data=df,method='nearest',replace=TRUE,ratio=2,discard="treat")     
m.out_none <- matchit(y~x1+x2,data=df,method='nearest',replace=TRUE,ratio=2,discard="none") 
# configure an output file to which the charts will be written
thePngFile <- png(file="matchit.png",width=960,height=480,units = "px")
# configure output file with 1 row and 2 columns
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(m.out_none,interactive=FALSE,type='jitter')
title(sub="out_none")
plot(m.out,interactive=FALSE,type='jitter')
title(sub="out")
dev.off()
```

The code produces the following output file.

[image]

Note that if the charts are specified in this manner as part of an R Markdown document, no extra output file is necessary. R will render the two charts in one figure within the output document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and examples. I do realized that `par(mfrow())` could do the trick, but the problem actually comes from adding other types of plot. For example, `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`, `plot(m.out,type='jitter')`, `plot(m.out, type='QQ')` will be problematic. This comes from the fact that the `plot` function in the `MatchIt` package wraps up several plots together, so when calling `plot(...,type='QQ')` it will overwrite the `par(mfrow())`. Sorry for the confusions in the reproducible code. I should have used `plot(...,type='QQ')`.

Comment: If MatchIt is overwriting `par()` it should be reported as a defect. Instructions for reporting defects in MatchIt are available on the [Matchit website](https://gking.harvard.edu/matchit).